# Blank screen on "Ionic dev app" and on "real mobile phone"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm new to Ionic and I followed [Ionic 4 doc](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs). I just install using `ionic start myApp sidemenu --type=angular` and didn't modify any code and it works on the browser without any issues. But when I check this on Ionic dev app on the phone it shows a blank page.

And I tried to build the "apk" file and tried to run on the phone. Again it shows the blank page.

Not sure what I missed, I just followed all the instruction mentioned in the doc.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you build the app with Cordova? Did you try debugging the app?

Comment: You can create andriod-debug.apk using ionic build cordova command and install the apk. You can debug the apk by launching "chrome://inspect" in chrome browser.

Comment: Try to view log using chrome://inspect

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, with Ionic Capacitor. On newer devices or on the web, everything worked ok, but on an older phone, with Android 9, I would get a blank screen.

The error that I got with Insect was at line

```
cap.handleError = err => win.console.error(err)
```

Another error for this problem was: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')

My solution was to modify in tsconfig.json
from "target": "es2020" to "target": "es2018"